# Akka Http Client Set Cookie on a HttpRequest

Tags: scala, cookies, akka-http

I am trying to make a GET request to a REST web service using Akka Http Client.

I am not able to figure out how do I set a cookie on the request before I make the GET.

I searched the web and I found ways to read the cookie on the server side. but I could not find anything which showed me how to set the cookie on the client side request.

Based on my own research I tried the following approach to set a cookie on http request

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model._
import akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.Unmarshal
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Sink, Source}
import akka.http.scaladsl.marshallers.sprayjson.SprayJsonSupport
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.headers.HttpCookie
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import spray.json._

import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

case class Post(postId: Int, id: Int, name: String, email: String, body: String)

trait JsonSupport extends SprayJsonSupport with DefaultJsonProtocol {
   implicit val postFormat = jsonFormat5(Post.apply)
}

object AkkaHttpClient extends JsonSupport{
   def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
      val cookie = headers.`Set-Cookie`(HttpCookie(name="foo", value="bar"))
      implicit val system = ActorSystem("my-Actor")
      implicit val actorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()
      implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher
      val mycookie = HttpCookie(name="foo", value="bar")
      val httpClient = Http().outgoingConnection(host = "jsonplaceholder.typicode.com")
      val request = HttpRequest(uri = Uri("/comments"), headers = List(cookie))
      val flow = Source.single(request)
         .via(httpClient)
         .mapAsync(1)(r => Unmarshal(r.entity).to[List[Post]])
         .runWith(Sink.head)

      flow.andThen {
         case Success(list) => println(s"request succeded ${list.size}")
         case Failure(_) => println("request failed")
      }.andThen {
         case _ => system.terminate()
      }
   }
}
```

But this gives an error

```
[WARN] [08/05/2016 10:50:11.134] [my-Actor-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(my-Actor)] 
HTTP header 'Set-Cookie: foo=bar' is not allowed in requests
```

Comment: `Set-Cookie` is the response header. For the request header, use the header name `Cookie` (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Setting_a_cookie).

Answer (score 5):

The idiomatic way to construct any header for an akka-http client is by 
using `akka.http.scaladsl.model.headers`.

In your case it would be

```
val cookieHeader = akka.http.scaladsl.model.headers.Cookie("name","value")
HttpRequest(uri = Uri("/comments"), headers = List(cookieHeader, ...))
```

Answer (score 2):

The outgoing header must be 'Cookie' not 'Set-Cookie':

```
      val cookie = HttpCookiePair("foo", "bar")
      val headers: immutable.Seq[HttpHeader] = if (cookies.isEmpty) immutable.Seq.empty else immutable.Seq(Cookie(cookies))
      val request = HttpRequest(uri = uri).withHeadersAndEntity(headers, HttpEntity(msg))
```